# How would you troubleshoot dependency errors that arise in Release mode only in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependencies

#### Context

We have an Android app built in Kotlin and we've split our algorithms layer into a separate Android Project. We import that as a dependency using Gradle using the following code:

In `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':algos-android')
}
```

This `algos-android` project has its own dependency - `koma` - defined in the `algos-android` project's `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation group: "com.kyonifer", name:"koma-core-ejml", version: "0.12"
}
```

#### Issue

This works completely fine when running the app in a `debug` mode (defined in `buildTypes` in the `build.gradle`). However, when running in `release` mode, we are seeing an error at runtime when our algorithms layer uses its sub-dependency - `koma`.

The following error shows up in the console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No double matrix factories available. (Did you forget to import a koma-core implementation?)
```

My team was under the assumption that Gradle handles sub-dependencies for us. Has anyone run into issues like this before? Are there any good debug approaches?

#### Things We've Tried

- Moving all of the files from our `algos-android` project directly into the main project and importing `koma` directly in the main project's `gradle.build` file.

#### Environment

- Android Studio 4.0.1
- Kotlin Version 1.3.72
- Gradle Version 6.3
- Subdependency Repo:
  https://github.com/kyonifer/koma

Answer (score 0):

We were finally able to track down the issue and resolve this with the following addition to the `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep class koma.** { *; }
```

We were able to find that since the Matrix factory classes are inflated in koma sources using reflection, proguard considered them as unused and simply deleted them from the release build.

**Note:** If you see this and make this fix, don't forget to Clean Project before running.